# Joi schema.validate a custom type return an undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi, hapi

I'm trying to validate a custom Type with JOI all with conversion.
the base type of my JoiType is a `Joi.array()`

when I try to

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
 attribute: Joi.array().items(Joi.string())
});

const result = schema.validate(exampleOfArray);
```

I found that `result.value` contains the real validated value.

But when I change the type to a custom type, **the value is not returned** : (`result.value === undefined`)

here is my custom type :

```
const customJoi = Joi.extend((joi: Root) => {
  return {
    type: 'stringArray',
    base: joi.array().items(joi.string()).meta({ baseType: 'array' }),
    coerce(value: any, helpers: CustomHelpers) {
      if (typeof value !== 'string') {
        return value;
      }
      if (!value) {
        return [];
      }
      return value.replace(/^,+|,+$/mg, '').split(',');
    }
  };
});

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
 attribute: customJoi.stringArray().items(Joi.string())
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

the coerce function should return :

```
return { value: value };
```

instead of :

```
return value;
```